# simple way to quickly edit my website

Tags: html, css, django, content-management-system, joomla

here's my website:

www.newportclassic.com

do you know of any free, easy to use, content management systems, that will allow me to simply edit the text on my site without having to download the file, open the file, edit the code, save the file, upload the file ???????

Comment: +1 I've been a fan of Newport Classic for ages!!

Comment: Depends on what services are available from the host.  WebDav?  FTP?

Comment: cool how did you find this post?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As an alternative to installing a CMS on your server, you might be interested in a service like [CushyCMS](http://www.cushycms.com/).  It allows you to specify what parts of your page are editable by setting an appropriate class in each editable `div` tag.  Then to edit the contents of those `div` blocks, you log in to the CushyCMS site and make your changes right there.  CushyCMS connects via FTP to the server for you and updates the HTML page.

Answer (score 4):

I know of a few CMS's that have done well, here are two of them.

1. Wordpress - free - http://wordpress.org/ - 3.0 is coming soon
2. Perch - paid - http://grabaperch.com/ - very light and easy

Answer (score 3):

[Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_content_management_systems) has a very good list of content management systems broken down by language and cost (open source/proprietary) and DBMS. Most of the ones I've used/evaluated in the past have been .NET based, such as DotNetNuke. Pretty much any CMS will give you the ability to edit your HTML without changing any files on your web server. If you're going for simplicity, the Wikipedia list has several that use a flat file instead of a database, so I would start there: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_content_management_systems#File_.2F_Flat_file

Answer (score 1):

You can use emacs -- it has a mode ([tramp](http://www.gnu.org/software/tramp/)) where you can open, edit and save remote files as if they were on your local machine. This makes it really easy to edit files on a webserver.

Comment: The Transmit FTP client for OSX does this too. Or you can just mount a SSH endpoint as a drive.

Comment: i said simple, did you see the documentation on tramp? come on mr. oakley

Comment: @every_answer_gets_a_point: Ignore the manual. Simply open "me@server:/path/to/file". That's all you have to do. To save, just save. It really doesn't get much easier than that. In other words, the only difference between opening a local file and a remote file is that you have to prefix it with your username and host name so it knows where to find it.

Answer (score 1):

In terms of user friendliness [zimplit](http://www.zimplit.com/index.html) is hard to beat.
Try their demo.
You can literally edit your website with a wysiwyg interface inside your browser.

Answer (score 1):

haven't used it myself but i've heard [Surreal CMS](http://surrealcms.com/) is quite good and easy to setup. Here's a [tutorial](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/cmss/a-15-minute-surreal-cms-integration/) to get you started.

Answer (score 0):

[Refinery HQ](http://RefineryHQ.com) is probably the easiest way to create, edit and update your website. You can upload images and files as you describe in your question.

You can also connect it to your own domain (it's a hosted service). So you'd be able to hook the site you create up to newportclassic.com